# Whatsapp backup recovery

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I am trying to get an old backup from one phone to another the problem is the phone from which am trying to get the back up from got stolen I still have access to all my accounts like Google Drive so I can see I have a back up on that other phone but I can't access it because I don't have the phone to get the verification code when am trying to log into WhatsApp so is there any solution to my problem i urgently need to check my messages and I cannot access that other backup onto my new phone.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Since you only have a backup on Google Drive, please take a look at the duplicate to retrieve the backup file directly. Good luck!